# Problem with React+Material-UI Layout, loosing features

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to react & material-UI. I'm trying to build an internal webpage with react.

For the dashboard, I want to use a theme from material-UI but split it up into different components.

- Theme: https://material-ui.com/getting-started/templates/dashboard/
- Source: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/docs/src/pages/getting-started/templates/dashboard

So, I started to split the different parts into different components. The AppBar in `<TopMenu />` and the Drawer in `<LeftDrawer />`, the main Content into `<Dashboard />`

If I do so, the content component will not resize on expanding the drawer. What am I doing wrong?

I uploaded my source to https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-euler-ftjen

It would be great if anyone can explain me my fault...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set `position: 'relative'` the container of drawer, here's sandbox link. https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-bassi-02k6e

Comment: Great, thanks for this fast help. Was blind to see that it was missing :-/

Comment: Great answer. I was struggling with this issue for weeks.